# System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission Cruise control Build

Tags: msbuild, cruisecontrol.net

I'm recieving the below error when i'm trying to build a VS solution file from cruise control.

**error ASPPARSE: Request for the permission of type 'System.Web.AspNetHostingPermission, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/4d5fb0b0-6530-4c36-8acd-b897f0c3b969

Looks like it is a permission issue on a shared directory.

Answer (score 0):

The official answer from Microsoft is to Configure Security Policy Using the Code Access Security Policy Tool (Caspol.exe). Unfortunately, this command line utility did not work for me. I however, do not rule out user error as to why it failed.

Ultimately, I solved my issue by running the .Net Framework Utility, and setting back my trust of the web server to FULL.

To change the local machine's .NET Security Settings goto

Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0 Configuration

Fully expand My Computer and select Runtime Security Policy. On the right, choose Adjust Zone Security. Leave the default option (Make changes to this computer) and hit next. Choose Local Intranet and change the trust level to Full Trust. Then choose Next and then Finish. Restart Visual Studio and you should be all set.